# Using both counts and averages in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I've got some data that I'd like to display both the averages and the count for.

For instance, there are 50 People taking a survey. Their names are saved in a Dimension "Raters". They are taste testing several products. These products are saved in a Dimension "Products"

They answer 4 questions. Taste, Texture, Appearance, Uniqueness, all saved in Dimension "Question"

The actual ratings are saved in "Ratings". This is a measure.

I can very easily make a table with Raters on the Rows, Question on the Columns, AVG(Ratings) in the text.

This shows me the average score for each question the rater answered.

It looks like this:

Rater-----Taste-----Texture-----Appearance-----Uniqueness

Joe---------2.2---------4.3--------------3.7-----------------2.4

Bob--------3.0----------1.2-------------3.4-----------------4.4

Sally-------4.5----------3.3-------------4.5-----------------3.2

Jessica---5.0----------3.0-------------2.0-----------------1.0

So far, so good.

Jessica's results look suspiciously integerish. When I look at the background data, I see that she only answered for 1 product.

I'd like to be able to add a column to the right of uniqueness which is the count of all product responses for that person.

I've played with this quite a bit, and I'm not sure that it is possible. Maybe with LOD?

I'd also like to filter the table, so that only "tough" raters are shown. Criteria for this is: Their average response for at least two criteria should be below 3.0. That would include Joe and Jessica.

When I try to do counts based on averages, I run into the "cannot aggregate an aggregate rule".

Is there a way around this? It would be trivial to do in excel with another column, a countif, and a filter.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:
You should be able to create a calculated field(Analysis->Calculated Field) and name it something like "Number of Records". In the query box just set it to 1 and select "Okay".

This new field will be selectable in the measures. Drag it into your table in the columns area and it should add a count next to your averages.

Part2:
In your measure values box you should be able to right click you measures. This will bring up a list of options including "Filter". Select this option.

On the SUM(Number of Records) set it to "At Least" = 2. Then right click on the AVG(Ratings) measure and set it to "At Most" = 3

Answer (score 0):

Put Products on the Rows shelf.

Then right click on that Products field on the Rows shelf and change ITT from a dimension to a measure. Be sure to choose Count Distinct for the aggregation.

Finally, right click on the field again and change it from continuous to discrete.

This shows how many different products each person reviewed, no matter how many characteristics they rated. If you want the number of ratings, use count instead of count distinct. Or just Sum(number of records), again set to discrete